# Launching a program and executing a command in bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script

How can I execute a command inside ROOT that I launch within the bash script? My aim is to have ROOT execute its GUI file browser and have it open if the user does not interfere with keyboard commands. I tried but failed since the GUI file browser stays open for a really short period of time. Is it possible that I modify the bash script and have the program open when the script terminates?

The description of ROOT can be found in the following link:

http://root.cern.ch/drupal/

Comment: Yes, a program can execute another program. What program is it? Your question is as vague as “can I drive a car on a road”. What is your actual question?

Comment: @Gilles I edited the question for clarity, thanks for pointing out the ambiguity.

Comment: Your question is still unclear. If program A has a command prompt, type the command at the command prompt. You seem to be running into some kind of problem, but you need to tell us what that problem is.

Comment: @Gilles Yes program A has a command prompt and I invoke the command by using the construct EOF, but when program A is closed without my interference and I would like to have it open as much as I please. Thanks for your interest by the way.

Comment: It seems that program A is doing something peculiar. **What is program A**? You need to give us the information!

Comment: @Gilles I edited my question and I hope it is clear enough now.

Comment: What is ROOT? Can you give a link to a description of that program? With a name that's identical to a Linux concept except for case, it's hard to google.

Comment: Okay editing it once more, you can find the description of ROOT in the provided link.

Answer (score 5):

just type the command and it will be executed:

```
#!/bin/bash
ls -l
```

if you want to run other shell scripts use:

```
sh otherShell.sh
```

or for executable files:

```
. otherShell.sh
```

gnuplot is as other commands, you can use it inside shell script:

Example:

```
#!/bin/sh
lib=$1
old="output/old/$lib.dat"
new="output/new/$lib.dat"

gnuplot << EOF
set logscale x
set logscale y
set size square
set grid
set pointsize 1
plot "< paste $old $new" using 1:4 ti '$lib'
EOF
```

for the problem "it was giving no time for view and interaction with the GUI launched within the application":
you can tell gnuplot to print the plot to file, which you can open up and view yourself:

```
plot '<SOME FILE>' .......
```

Or you need to invoke gnuplot with a flag:

```
gnuplot --persist
```

to ensure that plots stay up after gnuplot quits.

Sources:

[automate gnuplot plotting with bash](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/34440/automate-gnuplot-plotting-with-bash)

http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-and-scripting/146860-using-variables-gnuplot-within-shell-script.html

Comment: My point is that I will launch an application with the command say GNUplot ,it will be ROOT Data Analysis Framework in my case, and pass some command to be executed inside GNUplot.

Comment: Thanks for the edit it will be helpful, I think this will also work with other programs.

Comment: @Vesnog Yes as I know.

Comment: It works as intended but the application is closed immediately, giving no time for view and interaction with the GUI launched within the application(ROOT).

Comment: @Vesnog, see Updates

Comment: Since GNUplot is much more familiar to everyone I gave it as an example. The program I use is ROOT which is an OOP data analysing software used in particle physics.

Comment: @Vesnog, I have found this [PDF](http://www.tunl.duke.edu/documents/public/root/material/5/perdue_root_071509.pdf) I guess `Compiling and Running the Program Using a Shell Script section` will help you out

Comment: Well thanks that is the program I use and I can write the shell script now, but the browser windows is not displayed long enough for me to interact with it.